# Cannot trigger component's function in my react app

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I am currently working with react and I have runned into a problem this morning that i do not understand.

I am trying to handle a form submit from my component with a function by passing it in the onSubmit property but it does not trigger it. I then added a button to trigger a mock function with its onClick property, and i still got the same problem; it appears than I can't trigger my function and I cannot find any solution on the Google.

Here is my code so you can check it out:

```
import React from 'react';
import AgentsStore from '../stores/AgentsStore';
import AgentsActions from '../actions/AgentsActions';

class Agents extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = AgentsStore.getState();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    AgentsStore.listen(this.onChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    AgentsStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
}

onChange(state) {
    this.setState(state);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var user = {};

    user.name = this.state.newUser.name.trim();
    user.lastname = this.state.newUser.lastname.trim();

    if (user.name && user.lastname) {
        AgentsActions.createUser(user);
    }
}

onClick() {
    console.log('clicked');
}

render() {

    return (
        <div /*className='container'*/>
            <div className='alert alert-info'>
                Hello from Agents
            </div>

            <div className='panel panel-default'>
                <div className='panel-heading'>Create User</div>
                <div className='panel-body'>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                        <div className='form-group'>
                            <label className='control-label'>Name</label>
                            <input type='text'
                                   className='form-control'
                                   ref='nameTextField'
                                   value={this.state.newUser.name}
                                   onChange={AgentsActions.updateName} />
                        </div>
                        <div className='form-group'>
                            <label className='control-label'>Lastname</label>
                            <input type='text'
                                   className='form-control'
                                   ref='lastnameTextField'
                                   value={this.state.newUser.lastname}
                                   onChange={AgentsActions.updateLastname} />
                        </div>
                        <h4>Address</h4>
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <button  onClick={this.onClick} className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Agents;
```

I do not know if I am missing something in my code or there is an error but i am kind of desperate. Also I am basing my code on another file that i have which is working just fine...

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: you have two submit buttons, how do you want submit from outside of the form? Check if your submit handler method is triggered if you press enter of one of the input fields, if so and the button thats inside form still is not working while clicked, try changing it to `<input type='submit' (...)`

Comment: A simplified version of the same code(without AgentStore, AgentActions and Additional submit button) works for me. my codepen is here: http://codepen.io/gbhasha/pen/WxKYzE

So my guess is the problem could be in AgentActions.